# Changing display of element in Selenium Python does not work

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, input, display

I want to upload a file using Selenium, but first I need to make the input element visible. It looks like that:

```
<input class="tb_sK" type="file">
```

I tried changing the style.display using JavaScript with this code:

```
js = "arguments[0].style.display='block'"
driver.execute_script(js, upload_button)
```

The input now looks like this but is still invisible :

```
<input class="tb_sK" type="file" style="display: block;">
```

I'm not very familiar with html, but in the devtools, I saw this :
[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id8Q9.png)

There is nothing in element.style and the 'display' is in .tb_sK. So I think I must change this.

How can I do it ?

Comment: have you tried adding `!important` to make CSS ignore other rules?

Comment: @heitor Yes I tried this and it just doesn't change anything, the element stays : `<input class="tb_sK" type="file">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try removing the class attribute:

```py
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('class')", upload_button)
```

This way the input won't be affected by the CSS rule you showed in your print and thus won't be invisible anymore.

Comment: Removing the class seems to work! It is stuck off screen, I think I'll need to move it to another place of the hierarchy.